# Buildign nestjs application with webpack and using AWS SDK v3 gives me a lot of builded folders

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-sdk, nest, monorepo

I apologize in advance for the English, I am relying on a translator.

I have a monorepo schema project with NestJS. When i try to build my microservice, my `dist`  folder shows me a lot of subdierctories instead of a single build file,
like this:

[image: folder structure]

I have identified this behavior when using the aws sdk (Im using specificly the @aws-sdk/client-sqs)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sqs';
import { ISQSService } from '../interfaces';

@Injectable()
export class SqsService implements ISQSService {
  public async execute(body: unknown) {
    try {
      const sqsClient = new SQSClient();
      const params = {
        QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body),
      };
      const sendCommand = new SendMessageCommand(params);
      console.log('Sending message to sqs');
      const result = await sqsClient.send(sendCommand);
      console.log(
        `Order sent to the queue successfully with the message id ${result.MessageId}`,
        body,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message to SQS');
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

> If I comment all the execute method body or leave without using SQSClient references then the build is generated correctly (just de dist/apps/webhook-proxy/main.js)

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const lazyImports = [
  '@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module',
  '@nestjs/websockets/socket-module',
  'class-transformer/storage',
];

module.exports = (options, webpack) => {
  return {
    ...options,
    target: 'node',
    externals: [],
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            keep_classnames: true,
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
    output: {
      ...options.output,
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        checkResource(resource) {
          if (lazyImports.includes(resource)) {
            try {
              require.resolve(resource);
            } catch (err) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Node: v18.19.0
I think this issue is more related to webpack but just in case my nestjs version is nest-core: 10.0.0

Thanks in advance, <3

I'm expecting that all the build be placed in a single file